# A special case of Skolem-Nother 'sTheorem

Tags: division-algebras, division-ring

Assume that $D$ is a division ring and $n>1$ be a natural number. Let $a\in SL_n(D)$ be a torsion element. For example, $a^m=1$. Also consider that $F=Z(D)$. Therefore, $[F[a]:F]<\infty$. By Skolem-Nothere's Theorem, there exists an element $b\in GL_n(D)$ such that $bab^{-1}=a^i\neq a$ for some $ i \leq m$. Can we choose $b$ such that $b\in SL_n(D)$?

Comment: Have you worked out the case $n=2$, $D=F$?

Comment: When $n>2$, It is not difficult to find a   counterexample. Notice that  $b $ is unique.

Comment: I feel very disconnected here. I think I know all the terminology in here, but can't parse much of what you say. 1) How do you define $SL_n(D)$ when potential lack of commutativity makes it difficult to define the determinant. 2) How do you define $F[a]$? Ok, I guess we should view $F$ as a subset of $M_n(D)$ and look for the minimal ring containing $F$ and $a$. 3) But if that is the case then I don't see how Skolem-Noether would give you that claim?

Comment: (cont'd) It cannot possibly work for all $i$ as $bab^{-1}$ has the same order as $a$. 4) I don't think $b$ can be unique. If $b$ works, so does $ba$. As does $bx$ for all $x\in F$?